# WCF SOAP Request w/out Documentation

Tags: .net, xml, api, wcf, soap

We have been provided with a URL, a sample XML request document, and a single line of .net code showing us how to access an API. I am adamant that we need more help, they are adamant that this information is all we need. The URL looks like:

```
http://C66-comp.insure.com/IntegrationServices/Rating.svc
```

**NOTE: The URL leads to a 404 error. All requests I attempt to make in Postman, POST & GET requests, lead to a 404 error.**

The .svc extension and a bit of research leads me to believe we are meant to be making a WCF SOAP request using the XML file. The XML request sample they sent us looks like:

```
<ACORD>
<SignonRq>
<SignonPswd>
<CustId>
<CustLoginId>user</CustLoginId>
<SPName>com.safjera</SPName>
</CustId>
<CustPswd>
<Pswd>pwd</Pswd>
<EncryptionTypeCd>NONE</EncryptionTypeCd>
</CustPswd>
</SignonPswd>
<ClientDt>2018-01-19</ClientDt>
<CustLangPref>English</CustLangPref>
<ClientApp>
<Org>Wesa</Org>
<Name>EZLynx</Name>
<Version>1.1</Version>
</ClientApp>3:05 PM 07/02/2019
</SignonRq>
....
```

The single line of .net code they provide to show us how to use it is:

```
Dim response As String = client.SubmitAndRate("user", " pass", "user", "ITC", 1, 11, 1, #1/1/1800#, #1/1/1800#, 2, True, True, False, False, document.OuterXml)
```

Now I don't write .net code, but of course I can generally dissect what is going on in other languages when analyzing API sample calls. If I'm not mistaken, I'm literally just being provided with an example of someone calling a custom method named SubmitAndRate, with some list of arguments that aren't defined, that is executing the real code I need but cannot see.

Is there really anything I can do to successfully make a request using this data? Clearly I need more information, such as to see the contents of SubmitAndRate, right?

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I could not access the service URL. I also get a 404 error.

> Clearly I need more information, such as to see the contents of
>   SubmitAndRate

You are right, we should need more information about the invocation, otherwise, we can not make a successful call to the service.
`SVC` extension typically refers to the WCF service. If the service is available, we usually call the WCF service by using a client proxy. the client proxy class contains all the method details, definitions so that we can call the service properly. In order to generate a client proxy call, we could use the below method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
Here is a reference example of the call to the service.

```
//Instantiate a client proxy object.
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient calcClient = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
// Call the Add service operation.
double value1 = 100.00D;
double value2 = 15.99D;
double result = calcClient.Add(value1, value2);
Console.WriteLine("Add({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);
```

However, the precondition is that the service address is available.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, you don't need more than the endpoint, WCF services are self-documented, but, given that the URL is returning 404, then the service is not working at all and that's the actual issue that you have to resolve here.

`SubmitAndRate` is the service endpoint and it takes these strings as input

More info on [How to consume WCF WebService](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/consuming-wcf-service-in-windows-application/)